# Xcode - Allocations : Failed to attach to target process

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm trying to attach a process to see it's allocations performance on instruments, but it shows

> Failed to attach to target process -- Failed to execute loader thread
> for
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/liboainject.dylib
> in target; target process  likely exited

it means i can't attach this process? Or do I need to do something before I attach it (I have run instruments with root)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the app and restart your phone ,after launched, directly press cmd + I in Xcode instead of press run.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean the build folder and restarting your Mac. It worked for me.